# App with showing weather information runs on emulator not on actual phone

Tags: android, android-studio, weather-api

```
    /15 18:04:40: Launching 'app' on Xiaomi Redmi 6 Pro.
Install successfully finished in 7 s 219 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.weatherapp/com.example.weatherapp.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 31272 on device 'xiaomi-redmi_6_pro-1f01c0720405'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
    Installing application
    VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
W/mple.weatherap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking)
W/mple.weatherap: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking)
W/mple.weatherap: Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/WindowInsets;->CONSUMED:Landroid/view/WindowInsets; (light greylist, reflection)
W/mple.weatherap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->getAccessibilityDelegate()Landroid/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate; (light greylist, linking)
W/mple.weatherap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
W/mple.weatherap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
W/Looper: Slow Looper: Activity com.example.weatherapp/.MainActivity is 488ms late (wall=767ms running=0ms ClientTransaction{ callbacks=[android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem] lifecycleRequest=android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem }) because of 2 msg, msg 1 took 528ms (late=4ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=110)
W/mple.weatherap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/Insets;->of(IIII)Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 2df12b3, I07da2d9908
    Build Date                       : 10/04/18
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.25.03.01
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Reconstruct Branch               : 
    Build Config                     : S L 6.0.7 AArch64
I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff110, ME: 0x005ff066
I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
    android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 5204 bytes, containing 1 windows, 20 views
I/DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to api.openweathermap.org not permitted
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler$CleartextURLFilter.checkURLPermitted(HttpHandler.java:115)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:458)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:244)
        at com.example.weatherapp.MainActivity$DownloadJSON.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:60)
        at com.example.weatherapp.MainActivity$DownloadJSON.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:41)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
        at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:176)
        at com.example.weatherapp.MainActivity.GetInformation(MainActivity.java:141)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6616)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6593)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25929)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

**This is runtime block**
*I have tried android:text which was suggested and also enable  multiDexEnabled true in gradle(app) file*
nut nothing works for me
Can anyone help me out?..
**It is simple app only showing weather information from the api key it works on emulator but not on phone **

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be: `Cleartext HTTP traffic to api.openweathermap.org not permitted`.

Clear text means any information transmitted that is not encrypted, which means you are either trying to contact the API through an `http` url instead of `https`, or that the API of the device where you are running the code is higher than Android 9, where clear text communication was disabled.

Check out the official Android [documentation for this](http://the%20official%20Android%20documentation) and also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted) for further information.